# When was the site elevated from Beta status?

Tags: discussion

When was the big date Bioinformatics SE was no longer a beta site?

I would have thought there would have been fireworks and celebrations, or at least an announcement on this forum. Its certainly worthy of one. Congratulations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[59 sites were elevated from Betas on the 16 December.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-59-sites-that-just-left-beta) I can't tell you much more than that.

Good to have you back answering questions btw.

Comment: Its a very comprehensive answer, the link describes everything. Fairly astonished to see 'Vi and Vim' are also out of beta. I obviously underestimated both power tools.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, that one is a bit on us... moderators. We got notification by SE admins in early November about it, offering us to prepare an announcement for the community. I started writing a post for meta, but never finished it, and then I forgot about it, so really sorry about that.

Basically, we are considered a viable site. The definition of viable site is now shifting to a community strong enough to keep noise (i.e. completely unrelated, offensive or otherwise problematic questions/answers) at the site at minimum and that we do pretty well.

We won't have any time soon our own nice design of things (like small DNA badges of Biology.SE) so technically only very little changes. However, we should have a graduation election some time during 2022 or even maybe in 2023 (because so many sites were promoted at the same time).

We might have Community Promotion ads, etc in the future if they are of interest.

Finally, we won't ever have to worry that the site will be closed down (unless SE will do fine and I feel they are rather safe :-)).

So, in the end, there is only very little practical changing at the moment, but I am really excited we are a full SE community! Congratulations everyone!

Comment: Thanks @KamilSJaron its a good step forward because beta might not mean much to e.g. Pets SE, but it definitely has a meaning in coding and an exciting future.

Comment: So when do we get the visual branding goodies?

Comment: @DanielStandage they promoted plenty of sites at the same time. So I suppose it won't be too soon.